# Unresolved reference: junit4: Android ComposeUI testing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying to test the UI I built using jetpack compose in android and added these dependancies to set it up

```
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.1.0"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.0.5"
```

for the testing I was just starting to write the following

```
class LoginActivityComposeTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun socialPluginsTest() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            SocialLogins()
        }
    }
}
```

**The createComposeRule() which I am trying to import was not available. I've tried to manually import from `import androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.createComposeRule` But when I try to run the tests after that there is an error showing**

`Unresolved reference: junit4`

Here is the full build.gradle dependancies I am using

compose_version = '1.0.1'
retrofit_version = '2.9.0'

```
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-alpha01"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.1.0"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.0.5"
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No I did not , I pause this side project work because I was busy

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct import? I suggest double checking it with the documentation. (Also link the docs here)

Comment: After moving the Test file to (androidTest) folder, the issue solved.

Answer (score 7):

I placed the test file in the wrong folder; not in the test folder but in `androidTest` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)` to the top of your test class.

I can't say with 100% accuracy as I'm not sure what else might be causing that in your gradle setup, but I've ran into a similar issue, and that was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using test folder using this:
`testImplementation`, with androidTest folder using `androidTestImplementation`

Answer (score 1):

As said from @nguyen-hoà use `testImplementation` instead of `androidTestImplementation`. This depends from position test files in the structure of your project.
I solved with this configuration. If you use modularization, verify that import is in correct gradle file of your module.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to restart Android Studio for it to correctly find and import the required `androidx.compose.ui.test.*`

Answer (score 0):

import dependency like following:

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4-android:1.5.1")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will be useful for somebody. Even thou I have BOM: `implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.01.00"))` I had to still add version for `androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.6.0")`

When I had only the dependencie set for BOM `androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")` the Gradle could not find it.